# Inverted xy axes on touch screen

Tags: raspbian, touch-screen

I'm trying to install a LCD screen (RB-TFT3.2) on my raspberry pi (rasbpian jessie).
To do so, I followed [the documentation of the lcd screen](http://downloads.joy-it.net/send/31-raspberry-zubehoer/88-anleitung-touch-display-3-2-v2), which can be summed-up as such:

1. add `dtparam=spi=on` and `dtoverlay=waveshare32b:rotate=270` at the end of /boot/config.txt
2. add `fbcon=map:10` at the end of /boot/cmdline.txt
3. create */usr/share/x11/xorg.conf.d/99-calibration.conf* with the following content:

   ```
   Section "InputClass"
       Identifier    "calibration"
       MatchProduct    "ADS7846 Touchscreen"
       Option  "Calibration" "160 3723 3896 181"
       Option  "SwapAxes" "1"
   EndSection
   ```

   4. changed `/dev/fb0` into `/dev/fb1` in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/00-fbturbo.conf
   5. downloaded [the linked overlay](http://www.joy-it.net/anleitungen/rpi/tft32b/waveshare32b-overlay.dtb) and put it into /boot/overlays

After a nice reboot, the screen is detected and works almost fine. The only trouble is the fact that x and y axis seem to be inverted for the touch cursor (the mouse pointer works fine).

I tried to calibrate it using either ts_calibrate or xinput_calibrator. Trouble is, touchscreen works swoothly with these tools.

To sum it up, I can use ts_test perfectly but it doesn't work well for lxde. Would you folks have any ideas on what's going on ?